# Firestore: Received WebStorage notification for local change. Another client might have garbage-collected our state

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting the following error coming from `Firestore`.

```
"Firestore (7.24.0): Received WebStorage notification for local change.
Another client might have garbage-collected our state",
```

The issue seems to be coming from this exact line in Firestore JS SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/local/shared_client_state.ts#L759

I do have persistence support (offline support) enabled with:

```
firebase.firestore.enablePersistence({ synchronizeTabs: true });
```

I'm not too familiar with the internal implementation of the SDK, so it would be nice to know:

- What's a likely scenario for this to happen?
- What's the recommended action to recover from this error?

The UX in the app is just a hanged app that seems to fail in its read/write operations until the app itself is killed and restored.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error ? This error was reported to be seen using Safari Web Browser.

Comment: @marian.vladoi the app is a hybrid app build on top of Capacitor and the user able to reproduce this does have iOS, so yes, it's running in a native web view for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a known issue and Firebase Engineering Team is working on solving it.

I created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/174349657) with [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) for you.

However there is no ETA and all future updates will be provided on that thread.

Please “star” the issue to receive comments and status updates.

**#EDIT:**

I was informed by the Firestore Engineering Team that this log message doesn't affect the SDK functionality and you can ignore this message.
However we prioritize the issue in order to fix the root cause.

Comment: is this link public? https://issuetracker.google.com/174349657 I'm getting Access Denied.

Comment: I'm also encountering this problem. I commented on the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174349657?pli=1